# String operations in Python

Tags: nlp, nltk, python-3.5

I'm trying to get into NLP using NLTK and I understand most of the code below, but I don't understand what `x.sub("", word)` and `if not new_word in ""` mean. I'm confused.

```
text = ["It is a pleasant evening.", "Guests, who came from the US arrived at the venue.", "Food was tasty."]

tokenized_docs = [word_tokenize(doc) for doc in text]
print(tokenized_docs)

x = re.compile("[%s]" % re.escape(string.punctuation))
token_nop = []
for sentence in tokenized_docs:
    new_sent = []
    for word in sentence:
        new_word = x.sub('', word)
        if not new_word in '':
            sentence.append(new_word)
    token_nop.append(sentence)
```

Comment: What do you expect from this piece of code? Doesn't it do what you expect it to?

Answer (score 0):

For simple things like this, Python is actually self-documenting. You can always fire up a Python interpreter and call the `__doc__` function on a function to see what it does:

```
>>> import re
>>> print(re.compile(".*").sub.__doc__)
sub(repl, string[, count = 0]) --> newstring
    Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
    occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl.
```

So, we see, `sub` is simply the operation that does a substitution on the  given regular expression pattern. (If you're unfamiliar with regular expressions in Python, [check this out](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)). So, for example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Hello world"
>>> p = re.compile("[Hh]ello")
>>> p.sub("Goodbye", s)
'Goodbye world'
```

As for `in`, that's just checking if `new_word` is the empty string.

Comment: Oh I just misunderstood. In re.sub I thought the first parameter was what was being replaced, but it is actually what is replacing. So, regex.sub("",string) replaces first occurence of regex in string with ""?

Comment: @SavonBrown Yup, exactly. I've edited my answer to include an example.